# Как правильно организовать запросы к API

Tags: javascript, promise

Получаю все данные по пользователю из разных методов в один объект:

```
let client = {};
apiGetClient()
  .then((response) => {
    client = { ...client, ...response.data };
    apiGetClientInfo().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data };
      apiClientIdentities().then(response => {
        client = { ...client, ...response.data };
        apiClientAddresses().then(response => {
          client = { ...client, ...response.data };
          apiClientGuarantors().then(response => {
            client = { ...client, ...response.data };
            apiClientWork().then(response => {
              client = { ...client, ...response.data }
              apiClientContacts().then(response => {
                client = { ...client, ...response.data }
                console.log(client, "Client")
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

Я не понимаю как это переделать правильно на цепочку промисов,

```
apiGetClient()
  .then((response) => {
    return client = { ...client, ...response.data };

  })
  .then((client) => {
    apiGetClientInfo().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data };
    })
  })
  .then((client) => {
    apiClientIdentities().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data };
    })
  })
  .then((client) => {
    apiClientAddresses().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data };
    })
  })
  .then((client) => {
    apiClientGuarantors().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data };
    })
  })
  .then((client) => {
    apiClientWork().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data }
    })
  })
  .then((client) => {

    apiClientContacts().then(response => {
      client = { ...client, ...response.data }
    })

  })
  .then((client) => {
    console.log(client, "Client")
  })
```

Как я понял должно быть что то вроде этого но как вернуть все в один обьект?

Comment: указанные методы независимы друг от друга?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цепочка нужна там, где следующий запрос зависит от того, что вернет предыдущий.

В данном случае, так как результаты не зависят друг от друга, стоит вообще убрать цепочку и воспользоваться методом [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let client = {};
Promise.all([
    apiGetClient(),
    apiGetClientInfo(),
    apiClientIdentities(),
    apiClientAddresses(),
    apiClientGuarantors(),
    apiClientWork(),
    apiClientContacts()
])
  .then(responses => responses.map(r => r.data))
  .then(data => Object.assign(client, ...data))
  .then(client => console.log(client, "Client"));
```

Comment: А если сервер воспримет это как DoS-атаку?)

Comment: @andreymal, он и последовательные может принять за DoS атаку :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(async () => {
  let resClient = await apiGetClient();
  let resClientInfo = await apiGetClientInfo();
  let resClientIdenties = await apiClientIdentities();
  let respClientAddress = await apiClientAddresses();
  let resClientGuarantos = await apiClientGuarantors();
  let resClientWork = await apiClientWork();
  let resClientContact = await apiClientContacts();

  let client = {
    ...resClient.data,
    ...resClientInfo.data,
    ...resClientIdenties.data,
    ...respClientAddress.data,
    ...resClientGuarantos.data,
    ...resClientWork.data,
    ...resClientContact.data
  };
 console.log(client, "Client");
})()
```

Comment: лучше тогда уж завернуть все запросы в Promise.all

Comment: @nörbörnën, к твоему варианту это так же относится :)

Comment: @Grundy нет. я отвечал на вопрос ТС: "Я не понимаю как это переделать правильно на цепочку промисов"

Comment: @nörbörnën, это один из правильных вариантов, у тебя в ответе не до конца доделано